# How to get only changed input fields

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developing a settings component which should have input fields, that are filled with the current settings on the page load via Firebase.
They are essentially filled like this:

`<input type="text" #name="ngModel" name="name" value="{{ data.name }} ngModel">`

After clicking on a `Save` Button, either only the changed data or all the data should be written to the database.
Easy right?
Unfortunately when using the `ngForm` directive, `formData.name.value` returns an empty string, if the form remains untouched. Only after changing the input fields, the value is recognized.
How can I surpass this issue without a huge hassle?
As far as I know there isn't event an option to check if a single input field was tampered with. Only the whole form can be dirty or not.

Comment: Don't use HTML `value` attribute. You are bypassing Angular. Use `[(ngModel)]="data.name"` if you are using template driven form.

Comment: like above comment, but also to answer your comment, there **is** as way to check if an input field has been touched or not in template driven forms. Under the hood template driven forms is essentially a reactive form, so you have access to same functions. I also recommend you move on to reactive forms, totally worth learning!